# Get the list of all top level dirs in resource://* URLs

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

Typing `resource://`in Firefox's address bar automatically redirects to `resource:///` (notice the third slash, corresponding to root).

It leads to the omni.ja archive located in the browser directory :

```
jar:file:///usr/lib/firefox-trunk/browser/omni.ja!/
```

On the other hand, `resource://gre/` displays the content of the top level omni.ja

```
jar:file:///usr/lib/firefox-trunk/omni.ja!/
```

Other top level directories are available under the resource:// scheme like : `resource://shumway/` or `resource://unity/` (under ubuntu for example)

**Is there a convenient way to display all these resource://* top level directories?**

Like a page listing the following result : gre, shumway, unity etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Javascript: no, you cannot enumerate substations.

From C++: There is [`nsResProtocolHandler::CollectSubstitutions`](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/netwerk/protocol/res/nsResProtocolHandler.h#39).

Note however that `resource://` substitutions are not static and can change at any point. In fact, a lot of add-ons (incl. all SDK based ones) will register/unregister new substitutions at runtime.

To map URIs you know of back to the underlying URI (file:, jar:), you can use [`nsIResProtocolHandler.resolveURI`](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/netwerk/protocol/res/nsIResProtocolHandler.idl#44) from JS and C++.